# Counting number of positive and negative values group by some column mysql query

Tags: mysql, count

I have following layout of a mysql table:

```
+------+-------+-----+------+
| user |subject|month|change|
+------+-------+-----+------+
|Donald| Math  | Jan | 3.15 |
+------+-------+-----+------+
| Mike | Math  | Jan | 2.15 |
+------+-------+-----+------+
|Regan | Math  | Jan | 3.00 |
+------+-------+-----+------+
|Donald| Engl  | Febr|-3.05 |
+------+-------+-----+------+
| Mike | Engl  | Febr| 3.00 |
+------+-------+-----+------+
|Regan | Engl  | Febr|-3.00 |
+------+-------+-----+------+
|Donald| Geog  | Jan | 3.00 |
+------+-------+-----+------+
| Mike | Geog  | Jan |-2.15 |
+------+-------+-----+------+
|Regan | Geog  | Jan | 3.60 |
+------+-------+-----+------+
```

I have to count positive or negative change group by subject, at the same time get the name of the group. If I query the mysql table like this:

```
COUNT (*) FROM $table WHERE change>0 GROUP BY subject
```

It will only count the number of positive change (>0) group by subject column. It is not possible to get number of negative change (<0) and to get the group name (Math, Eng & Geog).

I want the result should be like that:

```
===============
Group | >0| <0|
===============
 Math | 3 | 0 | 
---------------
 Eng  | 1 | 2 |
---------------
 Geog | 2 | 1 |
---------------
```

What would be single mysql query in order to get the result like above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The query below will group the records by `subject`. MySQL supports boolean arithmetic since `a.change > 0` returns 1 for true and 0 for false.

```
SELECT  a.Subject,
        SUM(a.change > 0) `> 0`,
        SUM(a.change < 0) `< 0`
FROM    tableName a
GROUP   BY a.Subject
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c83396/2)

note, it doesn't include subjects where `change = 0`.

Comment: Would you please explain the code and how to fetch the result?

Comment: For your kind information that I don't want to get the sum of positive or negative changes, I want number of positive or negative occurrence of changes.

Comment: that's exactly what the query returns. click the sql fiddle link to see the results.

Comment: I could not understand one thing of your fiddle. You created a mysql table with column 'subject' (all in small letters). But in your query, you are selecting 'Subject' column (first letter capital). Then how the query can select the 'subject' column correctly?

Comment: mysql in sqlfiddle is case insensitive.

Comment: Simple, elegant. Good answer.